# How to use try catch to replace invalid data of user input array instead of restarting code in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, try-catch, java.util.scanner, user-input

Whenever invalid input is entered, such as a letter, the code starts from the beginning. How do I get it so that it keeps rebuilding the code from where invalid input was entered. I want it to kick out the invalid input, and prompt the user to re-enter a valid input, and keep building it.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Array {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    int z = 1;
    do {
      try {  
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
       
        double[] myArr1 = new double[10];  //Creates array
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Enter 10 elements: ");
        System.out.println("");
    
        for (int x=0; x<myArr1.length; x++) {
          myArr1[x] = scanner.nextDouble();  //Gets user input
        }  //end of for
    
    
        double sum1 = 0;
        for(double x=0; x<myArr1.length; x++) {
            sum1 += myArr1[(int) x];  //Defines sum1
        }  //end of for
    
        double[] myArr2 = new double[10];  //Creates array
        System.out.println("Enter 10 elements: ");
        System.out.println("");
    
        for (int y=0; y<myArr2.length; y++) {
          myArr2[y] = scanner.nextDouble();  //Gets user input
        }  //end of for
        double sum2 = 0;
        for (double y=0; y<myArr2.length; y++) {
          sum2 += myArr2[(int) y];
        }  //end of for
        System.out.println("Sum of first 10 elements is: " + sum1);  //Prints sum of first 10 elements
        System.out.println("Sum of second 10 elements is: " + sum2);  //Prints sum of last 10 elements
    
      }/*end of try*/catch (Exception e) {  //Catches errors in user input
         System.out.println("Invalid input. Try again: ");
         System.out.println("");
         }  //end of catch
    }//end of do
    while(z==1);
    return;
  }
}
```

Comment: Make the `try-catch` around the `scanner.nextDouble()` statements and not around the whole method?

Answer (score 1):

You can craft a helper method for input. It will continually prompt with the messages provided until a correct type is entered.  This tends to come in handy when inputs need to be taken from different locations within the program.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    double v = nextDouble(input, "Please enter a value: ", "Improper type, try again: ");
    System.out.println(v);
}
public static double nextDouble(Scanner input, String prompt, String error) {
    System.out.print(prompt);
    // loop forever
    for(;;) {    
       try {
          double v = input.nextDouble();
          return v;
       } catch (InputMismatchException ie) {
            input.nextLine(); // clear input buffer
            System.out.print(error);
           
       }
    }
}
```

Here is an example from your code.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String prompt = "Please enter a number: ";
String error = "Invalid input, try again";

double[] myArr1 = new double[10]; // Creates array
System.out.println("");
System.out.println("Enter 10 elements: ");
System.out.println("");

for (int x = 0; x < myArr1.length; x++) {
    myArr1[x] = nextDouble(scanner, prompt, error);
} // end of for

double sum1 = 0;
for (double x = 0; x < myArr1.length; x++) {
    sum1 += myArr1[(int) x]; // Defines sum1
} // end of for
```

Get rid of your existing try/catch blocks.  And I don't know why you have a `do/while` since you aren't looping more than once.

Comment: You can put the code (i.e. method) anywhere within your class but not inside main or any other rmethod.  You can call the method from where you would normally invoke the Scanner for input.

Answer (score 0):

or you can using while loop and a boolean value to get a number

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
boolean bool = true;
double d ;//= scanner.nextDouble();
while(bool){
    try{ 
        scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        d = scanner.nextDouble();
        bool = false; 
    }catch(InputMismatchException e){
        System.err.println("invalid input");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out. I had to create a boolean, but also decrement the index of the array of where the bad input was being placed (i = i-1). I also made it just one array and set the first 10 values to x and the last 10 to y to make it a little bit simpler.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Array {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double[] array = new double[20];  //creates array
        boolean on = true;  //sets value "on"

        while (on) {  //starts while loop
        

            System.out.println("Enter 20 numbers: ");
            System.out.println("");

            for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {  //creates user input prompt
            
                Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);  //gets user input

                try {
                    array[i] = input.nextDouble();  //assigns user input to array[i]
                }/*end of try*/ catch (Exception e) {  //catches invalid input
                
                    System.err.println("Invalid Input. Try again: ");
    
                    i = i - 1;  //decrements index of re-entered number
                }  //end of catch
            }  //end of for

            double x = 0;
            for (int z = 0; z < 10; z++) {
                x += array[z];
            }  //end of for
            System.out.println("Sum of first 10 numbers = " + x);  //adds first 10 numbers in array and assigns them to x

            System.out.println("");

            double y = 0;
            for (int z = 10; z < 20; z++) {
                y += array[z];
            }  //end of for
            System.out.println("Sum of last 10 numbers = " + y);  //adds last 10 numbers in array and assigns them to y

            on = false;  //breaks while loop
        }  //end of while
    }
}
```